# Uploading a file from javascript frontend to S3 bucket using presigned URL return error 400

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, django-rest-framework, file-upload, pre-signed-url

Hi I have set up an S3 bucket and a user that has read and write permissions.

I have a rest server backend that returns a presigned url using the code

```
def create_presigned_post(bucket_name, object_name,
                          fields=None, conditions=None, expiration=3600):
    """Generate a presigned URL S3 POST request to upload a file

    :param bucket_name: string
    :param object_name: string
    :param fields: Dictionary of prefilled form fields
    :param conditions: List of conditions to include in the policy
    :param expiration: Time in seconds for the presigned URL to remain valid
    :return: Dictionary with the following keys:
        url: URL to post to
        fields: Dictionary of form fields and values to submit with the POST
    :return: None if error.
    """

    # Generate a presigned S3 POST URL
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3',
                            aws_access_key_id=settings.AWS['ACCESS_KEY'],
                            aws_secret_access_key=settings.AWS['SECRET_KEY'])

    try:
        response = s3_client.generate_presigned_post(bucket_name,
                                                    object_name,
                                                    Fields=fields,
                                                    Conditions=conditions,
                                                    ExpiresIn=expiration)
        print(response['fields'])
        return response
    except ClientError as e:
        raise e
```

Using the returned response to the javascript frontend I try to perform the upload using the following code:

```
if (res.ok) {
                    const resData = await res.json();
                    let formData = new FormData();
                    let formFields = JSON.parse(resData['fields']);
                    formData.append('file', tarFile);
                    formData.append('key', formFields['key']);
                    formData.append('x-amz-algorithm', formFields['x-amz-algorithm']);
                    formData.append('x-amz-credential', formFields['x-amz-credential']);
                    formData.append('x-amz-date', formFields['x-amz-date']);
                    formData.append('policy', formFields['policy']);
                    formData.append('x-amz-signature', formFields['x-amz-signature']);

  const response = await fetch(resData['url'], {
    method: 'POST',
    body: data,
  });
  return response;
```

However I then receive an error 400 in my fronted.
If i send the post request from my backend with the code:

```
response = create_presigned_post('BUCKET_NAME', object_name)
if response is None:
    exit(1)

# Demonstrate how another Python program can use the presigned URL to upload a file
with open(object_name, 'rb') as f:
    files = {'file': (object_name, f)}
    http_response = requests.post(response['url'], data=response['fields'], files=files)
# If successful, returns HTTP status code 204
logging.info(f'File upload HTTP status code: {http_response.status_code}')
```

Then everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

Adding the keys in the wrong order to the form

Use a for loop to preserve the order of the fields

```
                Object.keys(formFields).forEach((key) => {
                    console.log(key)
                    formData.append(key, formFields[key]);
                });
```

Thanks to this guy: [Secure browser-based S3 uploads: signed policy doc or presigned URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41308886/secure-browser-based-s3-uploads-signed-policy-doc-or-presigned-url)